# Execute command using plink.exe

Tags: powershell, plink

I am trying to execute some command using plink.exe from powershell

below is the code which is working fine

```
plink.exe root@1.1.6.2 -pw $password -m "C:\command.txt" -no-antispoof
```

in **command.txt**, I have mentioned command as **df -h**

but when I tried to execute the command directly, it is not not returning any value.

```
plink.exe root@1.1.6.2 -pw $password "df -h" -no-antispoof
```

Please let me know what I am missing here. I have to execute multiple commands in various parts of my code. creating text file each command is getting difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put `plink` switches after the command. This should work:

```
plink.exe root@1.1.6.2 -pw $password -no-antispoof "df -h"
```

Comment: Thanks for you response @Martin Prikryl, but still it is executing without error and no output

Comment: `plink.exe root@1.1.6.2 -pw $password -no-antispoof "df -h"` and `plink.exe root@1.1.6.2 -pw $password -m "C:\command.txt" -no-antispoof` with `C:\command.txt` containing `df -h` are equivalents. If one works, the other should work too. Add `-v` to both and post a complete outputs you get. Run them on command-line, not from any PowerShell script, to rule out external influences.